# How to detach process in a server with X windows?

Tags: ssh, screen, tmux

Can you help me with this problem?

I want to detach a process I start in a server. This process is an application with one window/widget (similar to gedit, kate...). I access to the server by means of ssh -X, and run the binary process in a terminal. I have used screen and tmux, but the problem is that once I run the process, the window is oppened remotely from the server to my computer. Then, I would like to let the process openned, so I close the screen/tmux, and  once I exit the ssh connection, the terminal waits till I close the process window, thus killing the process in the server.

Is there any way to let the process detached even with the process X windows?

Thank you,
James

Comment: use background forking. eg `command &`

Comment: @AizuddinZali this will not help, because the program needs to communicate with the X server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33043963/2196426):

I don't think it is possible over `ssh`. When you have such process, it needs to communicate with the X server (which is running on your client). You can't just take it away from the process.

If you need to run processes with X detached, you need to use X server on that remote machine. For this use case, VNC is probably better solution, since it can create virtual displays that are available even after disconnect.

Comment: Take a closer look at ssh, options, and tunnels =) https://calomel.org/firefox_ssh_proxy.html Also the OP does not want to run the  app on the server, well X is forwarded.

Comment: yes,  after installing it, I have been able to access the server from my client. Despite the installation can be a little bit confusing, using VNC with VNC viewer (vinagre) gives good results! 

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Use better ssh options

```
nohup ssh -p xxxx -i ~/.ssh/key -X -C -c blowfish -N user@server <command> &
```

-p port (if you are not using the default 22)
-x = allows X forwarding
-C -c = compression and compression protocol (IMO blowfish is fastest)
-N = no console
nophu - allows you to close the terminal if you wish

= command to run (gedit, etc)

Depending on what you want, you can port forward (better of apps such as firefox).

Comment: I didn't succeed to solve the problem with nohup. Same error. VNC was a good solution for it. Thank you anyway